# Function that takes map and only cares about key type

Tags: go

I have two maps, both of them are keyed by `strings`, but the values are of two different custom types.

```
map[string]type1
map[string]type2
```

Now I want to write a function which can take an argument of either of these two types, because that function only looks at the keys and doesn't care about the values at all. So I think it should look like this:

```
func takeTheMap(argument map[string]interface{}) {
...
```

But that doesn't work due to:

```
cannot use myVariable (type map[string]customType) as type map[string]interface {} in argument to takeTheMap
```

https://play.golang.org/p/4Xkhi4HekO5

Can I make that work somehow?

Comment: It would help if you'd state what's your use case and why precisely do you need such cruft? I can think of another solution that would work for you, but since it also involves the empty interface, it's even cruftier than what you already have.

Comment: A. Create an interface with `Get(k string) interface{}` and then declare the two custom map types and have them implement that interface. B. Use the empty interface (`interface{}`) as the argument to your function and have the function use reflection to retrieve the provided map's values.

Comment: @Havelock I'm working on a service which needs to hold multiples types of indexes in memory, those nested maps are the different index types. But some methods needs to perform the same operations on both index types, that's why i'd want them to be generic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only polymorphism in Go is interfaces. The only alternatives to that are reflection, duplication, or rethinking the broader design so that you don't need to do what you're trying to do here.

If the last option isn't a possibility, personally I would recommend duplication, since it's a whole four lines of code.

```
keys := make([]string, 0, len(myMap))
for key,_ := range myMap {
    keys = append(keys,key)
}
```

A big complicated generic helper seems kind of unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

A solution using an interface. This example may seem a bit overkill and it may be better to in your case (I'm not sure, not enough details in your example) to just use a couple of `for` loops.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type foo bool
type bar string

type mapOne map[string]foo
type mapTwo map[string]bar

func (m mapOne) Keys() []string {
    s := []string{}
    for k := range m {
        s = append(s, k)
    }
    return s
}

func (m mapTwo) Keys() []string {
    s := []string{}
    for k := range m {
        s = append(s, k)
    }
    return s
}

type ToKeys interface {
    Keys() []string
}

func main() {
    m1 := mapOne{"one": true, "two": false}
    m2 := mapTwo{"three": "foo", "four": "bar"}

    doSomething(m1)
    doSomething(m2)
}

func doSomething(m ToKeys) {
    fmt.Println(m.Keys())
}
```

Playground [example](https://play.golang.com/p/ngljXzIdAn4)